# Selected item in grid1 shows its related items from tabele2 in grid2

Tags: c#, datagridview, ado.net

I'm trying to achieve the following:

I have my first grid which shows the entries from my db `table foo`, when selecting one, I need to recover from  column[0] cell[0], an id which I'll use for a query afterwards. This query will populate grid2 with all the one-many instances from `table bar`. But i get an null point exception and i cannot figure out why...

```
private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlConnection sc = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source = WARZARU-NB\SQLEXPRESS; Database = proj_1; Integrated Security = True");

            dataSet.Clear();

            dataAdapter.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand("select * from students WHERE id=@index", sc);
      // EXCEPTION here
            dataAdapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@index", SqlDbType.Int).Value = dgParent.CurrentCell.Value; 
            dataAdapter.Fill(dataSet, "grades");

            dgChild.DataSource = dataSet.Tables["grades"];

            dgParent.AutoResizeColumns();
            dgParent.AutoResizeRows();
        }
```

Comment: Well, `dgParent.CurrentCell` returns `The DataGridViewCell that represents the current cell, or null if there is no current cell. The default is the first cell in the first column or null if there are no cells in the control.` Are you sure there is at least a row/cell in dgParent when you call `CurrentCell`?

Comment: Well they are printed, since i can see them in table, i suppose they are... :(

Comment: Hmm, try maybe `dgParent.Rows[0].Cells[0].Value` ? Although I think you'll get the same exception.

Comment: Still  the same problem...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Still not the right way to do it, but it works...

```
  private void dgParent_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            SqlConnection sc = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source = WARZARU-NB\SQLEXPRESS; Database = proj_1; Integrated Security = True");
        if (dgParent.SelectedCells.Count > 0)
        {
            dgChild.DataSource = null;
            int selectedrowindex = dgParent.SelectedCells[0].RowIndex;
            DataGridViewRow selectedRow = dgParent.Rows[selectedrowindex];
            string a = Convert.ToString(selectedRow.Cells["id"].Value);
            MessageBox.Show(a);

            SqlCommand updateCommand1 = new SqlCommand("Select * FROM tableChild WHERE studentID = @id", sc);
            updateCommand1.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("id", a));
            dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(updateCommand1);

            dataSetChild.Clear();
            dataAdapter.Fill(dataSetChild, tableChild);
            dgChild.DataSource = dataSetChild.Tables[tableChild];
        }

        dgParent.AutoResizeColumns();
        dgParent.AutoResizeRows();
    }
```